# How to Generate Spring Boot REST Client with Swagger

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, swagger

I want to generate a Spring Boot Rest Client jar from swagger.json file. I referred this [link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-rest-client-swagger-codegen) and after I run the "*java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate*" with valid arguments, It has generated an Java Spring project. But, I want to generate jar file for calling remote server API (which I got swagger.json).

Can someone please help me to do this properly?
Thanks

Comment: you already get spring project

Comment: then you can build jar with `gradle build` command

Comment: I'm using maven as a build tool, let me try to build using maven

Comment: Did you manage to do it? I have client generated as jar. Now I am trying to find how to use it in my other spring boot app.